# Incremeting static variable in windows forms

Tags: c#, sql, static

I created a static variable called loanID  this way:

```
class Loan:Person
{
    public static int loanID;
    public static string loanstatus = "Active";
    public Loan(string cusno,double loanamount)
    {
        Customernumber = cusno;
        Loanamount = loanamount;
        loanID += 1; 
    }
    public double Loanamount
    {
        get;set;
    }
```

Everytime I give a user a loan I want it to increment and assign that curent loanID value as the loanID for loan that is currently being taken. I am able to enter the loanID into a database table. But everytime I run the Loans form the static variable seems to be reset and starts from 1 again.

Below is the code where I get the value of the static variable and send it to a database. It happens in a different class called Registration

```
string insert = ($"insert into Loan values('{loaner.Customernumber}','{details[0, 1]}','{loaner.Loanamount}',GetDate(),'{GetUser()}','{Loan.loanID}','{details[0, 2]}','{Loan.loanstatus}');");
```

This string insert is then passed as a parameter to a method called ExecuteCommand to insert to database

```
 public static int ExecuteCommand(string sql)
    {
        DBGateway letsee = new DBGateway();
        //SqlConnection conec = letsee.Connected();
        SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand(sql, letsee.Connected());
        int row = insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
        
        letsee.Closed();
        return row;
    }
```

Comment: please use ***parameterised queries*** - building SQL queries by concatenation etc. is a recipe for disaster. not only is it a source for many hard to debug syntax errors, it's also a wide, open gate for ***[SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)***. also: it's best to let the database worry about auto-incrementing IDs. also: every time you "run the loans form"? or every time you "run the program"?

Comment: *I created a static variable called loanID this way:* - we don't do this, we use a database that calculates and maintains the ID for us, and we query it after we insert if we want to know what it is.`sql = INSERT INTO x(y,z) VALUES(@y,@z); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` - executescalar it

Comment: (also: your inheritance is not the best choice.. a `loan` is _not_ a `person` - a loan is something a person _has_.)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann thanks for the help I ended up using the autoincrement strategy by using identity in the database table and I am now using parameterized queries.